# What should be passed in the timingCompatibility variable of the findsequence2 API?

Tags: here-api, waypoint, here-routing

I'm trying to use this API : https://wps.hereapi.com/v8/findsequence2
(documentation here https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/api-reference.html)

This variable : timingCompatibility (string)
is proposed but undocumented.

What should be passed in it?
What is its purpose?

I am trying to delay the departure of a car/truck to match first opening time on my sequence, I thought it might help but tried a a few values without success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **timingCompatibility=true** enforces WSE to synchronize with the travel times of the Router (WSE uses the Matrix-Router by default). The travel times are cross-checked after the sequence has been established and there will be no influence on the order of the waypoints. It is intended to have precisely consistent timings between WSE and the subsequent usage of Router (V7.2). My expectation is, that this parameter will not be necessary anymore with the migration of WSE to use Matrixrouter V8. This migration is progress.